# LocationUpdates module in Android Studio - How can I include the date with the time and have it update with the coordinates?

Tags: java, android

Here's the code it currently relies on for updates:

```
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %s",
                mLastUpdateTimeLabel, mLastUpdateTime));
```

I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText("Date/Time:"+ " " + currentDateandTime);
```

and that at least printed date and time. However, it doesn't update with coordinates. Any idea how to make it update with coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

changed

```
mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

to

```
mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```